# struts2 i18n java properties, how to escape characters?

Tags: java, file, properties, struts2

I don't know how to escape ' in a java properties file. I'm using struts2 and getText function to fill i18n and text tags.

For example I use:
config.users.title= taula d'usuaris   ---> config.users.title= taula d\'usuaris

But in my JSP, I get : taula dusuaris.

I use this to display text on my JSP:

```
<label for="title"><s:text name="config.users.title" />:</label>
```

Also I sometimes I use:

```
<s:select id="categories"  name="categories"  headerKey="" 
headerValue="%{getText('map.categories.all')}"
list="categories" listKey="id" listValue="name"/>
```

What's the error?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in the way how you displayed it. Now, edit and update your question to include information about the way how you displayed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks lucentmind and BalusC foryour repliees

the solution was this: on my properties file I quoted ' as \'' and works fine.

```
**taula d \''usuaris**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use double quote as escape character to show  single quote on HTML page.

so you can mention value in propertis file like this : **taula d "\'"usuaris**